# MissingManifestResourceException publishing to twitter from windows phone 8.1 app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, tweetinvi

I can publish to Twitter from the emulator.

My code:

```
private async Task PublishTweet()
    {
        StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("shareImage.png");
        var credentials = TwitterCredentials.CreateCredentials(App.localSettings.Values["TwitterAccessToken"].ToString(),
            App.localSettings.Values["TwitterAccessTokenSecret"].ToString(),
            "XXX", "XXX");

        TwitterCredentials.SetCredentials(credentials);
        byte[] file1 = await ReadFile(file);
        var shareTweet = Tweet.CreateTweet(App.ViewModel.CurrentItem.Description + " #" + ResourceLoader.GetForCurrentView().GetString("Hashtag"));
        shareTweet.AddMedia(file1);

        var result = await shareTweet.PublishAsync();

                }
```

But debugging from device, throws the MissingManifestResourceException at the last line

```
var result = await shareTweet.PublishAsync();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most recent versión of Tweetinvi (0.9.8.1) solves the problem